# SysFs interface. I can't export gpio pins in a Xilinx's Board (Zybo and other)

Tags: linux, kernel, xilinx, gpio, zynq

Using a linux-kernel compiled as it is described [here](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Getting+Started), I'm trying to make a led blinking following this wiki: [Linux GPIO Driver](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Linux+GPIO+Driver). I'm working with a Zybo-board of Xilinx.

I enabled the kernel options:

```
CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_GPIO_XILINX=y
```

I checked that I have mounted in /sys the SysFs

I want to configure the pin 7 of the MIO port because it is attached to the led LD4 in the board. So I used this expression:

```
echo 7 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

And I always obtain this error:

```
export_store: invalid GPIO 7
ash: write error: Invalid argument
```

I have also tried to export the values `145 (138+7)` because of the explanation I found here: [forum_link](http://zedboard.org/content/error-while-exporting-gpio) and 86 because this guy got the things working [basic_example](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2014/07/bash-gpio-xillinux/). But I always obtained the same error.

Could you give me some help? Maybe a I have to use other offset? Or is it more related with permission configuration??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problem. The solution is to add 906 as a "base" of the "address-gpio". For example, if you want to manage the pin of the PS connected to MIO 7, you should do something like this:

```
zynq> echo 913 > /sys/class/gpio/export
zynq> echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio913/direction
zynq> echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio913/value
```

(where 906+7=913 of course).

Or, if you want to switch it off:

```
 zynq> echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio913/value
```

How do I find this value? Well, in my case I was just lucky: if you have a look in

```
ls /sys/class/gpio
```

you can see that it already exists `gpiochip906`. Go inside this directory and have a look inside the file `base` (using "less" for example): there is only the value 906 of course